# Handlebars Dynamic parameters

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

This must be a real novice question but I've look at all the top answers on StackOverflow and I just don't see my answer. Sorry if it was already answered.

I'm simply doing a loop over multiple categories. For some reason the parameters of my helper isn't dynamic. It takes it as if it was a string.

```
{{#each catalog.catalog_categories}}
    alert({{this.category_name_en_sh}} ); // Alert "Computer
    {{&categoryHelper this.category_name_fr_sh}}
{{/each}}
```

In my app.js

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('categoryHelper', function(category) {
    alert(category)  // Alert category_name_fr_sh
    ...
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use helper, not registerHelper

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('categoryHelper', function(category) {
  alert(category);
});
```

registerHelper is the appropriate use if you are using stock handlebars, not the ember handlebars.

http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/

Comment: Thank you, may I ask what the difference is and when I should use the registerHelper?

Comment: np, registerHelper is for use with the non ember version of handlebars.